# Where can I find the default Realm Database file

Tags: android, database, migration, realm

I started working on the logic for my migration, using this code:
https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample/MigrationExampleActivity.java

And after writing the code, I get an error at this line:

```
String path3 = MigrationClass.copyBundledRealmFile(this, this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.default1), "default1");
```

It can't find the R.raw.default1 file, because until now, I used the default Realm like this:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(context);
```

My question is where can I get the file path for this realm file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Realm just uses the Context to call `getFilesDir()` and the default Realm is called `default.realm`. So in your case you should use:

```
String realmPath = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "default.realm").getAbsolutePath();
Realm.migrateRealmAtPath(realmPath, new CustomMigration());
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get the path of your realm file by calling the "getPath()" method:

Here an Example:

```
realm.getPath()
```

Comment: But I can't find the default.realm file in my ph storage path. Something wrong with me ?